# Fluent movement in a single keypress

Tags: java, game-development

Well, i am making a game right now. It is basically a "shooting game", where you shoot the other player. Well, everything is fine but the movement of the characters bugs me a lot. Don't understand me wrong here, I can program the movement of the characters and it's working kinda... but not fluent. Let me explain the word "fluent". Right now, the movement of my characters are like this; If I press "right arrow" to move the character to the right, it keeps going until i don't press the key anymore. I want to get rid of that, instead I want to move my characters in a single KeyPress to the right and it should keep going to the right until i press the "left arrow".

```
public class Character extends Main implements KeyListener {
int x;
int y;
int width;
int height;



public Character() {
    this.x = 250;
    this.y = 400;
    this.width = 30;
    this.height = 30;
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setVisible(true);
```

}

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D mainGraphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    mainGraphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mainGraphics.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    mainGraphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mainGraphics.fillRect(Enemy.xEnemy, Enemy.yEnemy, Enemy.widthEnemy, Enemy.heightEnemy);
    mainGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
    mainGraphics.fillRect(Fire.xFire, Fire.yFire, Fire.widthFire, Fire.heightFire);

    mainGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
    mainGraphics.fillRect(FireEnemy.xFireEnemy, FireEnemy.yFireEnemy, FireEnemy.widthFireEnemy, FireEnemy.heightFireEnemy);


    }



public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {


}


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {


}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
        this.x = this.x - 10;
        Fire.xFire -= 10;
    }
    else if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
        this.x = this.x + 10;
        Fire.xFire += 10;
    }
    else if(keyCode == e.VK_A) {
        Enemy.xEnemy -= 10;
        FireEnemy.xFireEnemy -= 10;
    }
    else if(keyCode == e.VK_D) {
        Enemy.xEnemy += 10;
        FireEnemy.xFireEnemy += 10;
    }
    else if(keyCode == e.VK_P) {

            Fire.xFire = this.x;
            Fire.yFire = Fire.yFire - 45;

        if(this.x == Enemy.xEnemy && Fire.yFire <= Enemy.yEnemy) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 won");
        }



    }
    else if(keyCode == e.VK_W) {
        FireEnemy.xFireEnemy = FireEnemy.xFireEnemy + 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
            FireEnemy.yFireEnemy = FireEnemy.yFireEnemy + 45;
        }

        if(Enemy.xEnemy == this.x && FireEnemy.yFireEnemy >= this.y) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 won");
        }



    }

    repaint();

}
```

}

My main class

```
    public class Main extends JPanel {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            Character character = new Character();
            Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
            Fire fire = new Fire();
            FireEnemy fireEnemy = new FireEnemy();
            window.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);
            window.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.add(character);
    }
```

}

Fire, FireEnemy, Enemy are just classes that are Empty, i just put "static int..." and a constructor in it. Nothing important are in those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last pressed key. Then keyPressed is called, check if the key is the same as the last stored. If so, just return, otherwise process it.

In the Character class, create this member:

```
int lastKeyCode;
```

In  your keyPressed method, add something like this:

```
int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
if (keyCode == lastKeyCode) return;
else lastKeyCode = keyCode ;
```

and use the code you alrady have.
Note: I will not write your program for you, just point you in the right direction. Since you are a beginner it will help you better in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by installing booleans in my keyPress method and bound it with if statements in the paint method. All working now.